# Chrome Extension Error - Website with Youtube embed video

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, chromecast

I have a website that has a embed youtube video. Im getting the following errors but I have no idea why. Im not developing any app for chrome. It is just a website with a video.

The errors Im getting are the following:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd/cast_sender.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED chrome-extension://dliochdbjfkdbacpmhlcpmleaejidimm/cast_sender.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED chrome-extension://hfaagokkkhdbgiakmmlclaapfelnkoah/cast_sender.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED chrome-extension://fmfcbgogabcbclcofgocippekhfcmgfj/cast_sender.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js
```

Any ideas on how to avoid those errors?

Comment: Are these causing any issues for you?

Comment: Nope... just that it is showing errors but apparently everything is working.

Comment: You can ignore those ... it is trying to see if the extension is installed or not; nothing to worry about.

Comment: Still, is pretty annoying to see that on the console, Im a big fan of "clean consoles", anybody can add something ? Im very looking forward to fix this :) 

Thanks

Comment: @AliNaddaf Please link to a source which verifies this