# Embedding youtube video is throwing extension error

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, video-embedding

I have found same question here [Chrome Extension Error - Website with Youtube embed video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833940/chrome-extension-error-website-with-youtube-embed-video),but it doesn't have a good answer.

I have `embedded` youtube video on `index page` of my site.When I search on google,title shows,`An error occured`

[image]

`Inspecting Element` shows me `6 extension error`.I get the following error

```
chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
chrome-extension://dliochdbjfkdbacpmhlcpmleaejidimm/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
chrome-extension://hfaagokkkhdbgiakmmlclaapfelnkoah/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
chrome-extension://fmfcbgogabcbclcofgocippekhfcmgfj/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
chrome-extension://eojlgccfgnjlphjnlopmadngcgmmdgpk/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

When I don't `embed` youtube video,I don't get any error neither on `google search` nor on `inspecting element`.

How can I get rid of this problem?Need your help real badly.

Thanks for your time.